# Reverse geocoding speed

Tags: r, apply, ggmap

I'm using R to extract latitude and longitude from a data frame and then getting an address using reverse geocoding.

I have some toy data here:

```
latitude <- c(40.84935,40.76306,40.81423,40.63464,40.71054)
longitude <- c(-73.87119,-73.90235,-73.93443,-73.88090,-73.83765)
x = data.frame(latitude,longitude)
```

I write a function to do the actual geocoding:

```
require(ggmap)
get_address <- function(df){
      long <- as.numeric(df$longitude)
      lat <- as.numeric(df$latitude)
      revgeocode(c(long,lat))
    }
```

Then apply:

```
apply(x,1,get_address)
```

Using `system.time()`, this takes about a second.  However, I plan to do this for data with over a million observations.  If it's going to take a while to run, I don't mind, but since I'm fairly new to this, I never know whether long running times are just an inevitable part of getting the data or are due to poor function design.  Is there an obvious way to significantly speed up this operation?

EDIT:

I learned from commenters that I'm going to be limited in the number of free requests (2,500/day) I can make.  All of my data comes from New York, and the purpose is to match latitude/longitude coordinates with a borough name.   Before I found out about the daily restrictions for free users, I had planned to get the address from Google using lat/long coordinates, extract the zip code from this address, then match the zip to a borough.  Does anyone have suggestions on how to do this without using the Google Maps Geocoding API?

Comment: You've got a bigger problem, you know. Google will throttle you very early on. Are you paying for additional access or are you going to be limited to the free amount?

Comment: Without seeing the code of the revgeodocde function, it is difficult to say anything about it. What is sur eon the other side is that you could easily paralellise the apply() call.

Comment: Prices: https://developers.google.com/maps/pricing-and-plans/#details

Comment: Oh, okay I didn't know that.

Comment: what geocoding resolution do you require?

Comment: At minimum, I would like to be able to identify NYC borough from the coordinate (maybe also neighborhood, but that isn't essential right now).  So I guess that would be the 3rd or 4th decimal place?

Comment: I think you can get quite a bit of mileage out of @SymbolixAU's answer, then. For that resolution, point-in-polygon shld be great and quite fast in `sf`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could find a 'spatial' data source of the boroughs, then perform geometric operations to find points in polygons using the [`sf`](https://github.com/r-spatial/sf) library

---

#### Setting up the data

Find a spatial data source. Here is one of the neighbourhoods in geojson format

```
library(sf)

sf <- sf::st_read("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/blackmad/neighborhoods/master/new-york-city-boroughs.geojson")
```

Convert your coordinates into a `sf` object. I've swapped your lat & lon column order.

```
latitude <- c(40.84935,40.76306,40.81423,40.63464,40.71054)
longitude <- c(-73.87119,-73.90235,-73.93443,-73.88090,-73.83765)
x = data.frame(longitude, latitude)

sf_x <- sf::st_as_sf(x, coords = c("longitude", "latitude"))
```

To perform spatial operations, the coordinate reference system needs to match between the two geometries

```
## set the cooridnate reference systesm to be the same
st_crs(sf_x) <- st_crs(sf)
```

use `st_within` to find the polygons (neighbourhoods) each point is in

#### Point-in-polygon calculation

```
res <- st_within(sf_x, sf)  ## return the indexes of sf that sf_x are within
```

This gives you a sparse matrix of the indexes of the polygons that each point is in

```
## view the results
sapply(res, function(x) as.character(sf$name[x]))
# [1] "Bronx"     "Queens"    "Manhattan" "Brooklyn"  "Queens"
```

---

#### Visual

Confirm with a plot

```
library(googleway)

x$neighbourhood <- sapply(res, function(x) as.character(sf$name[x]))

mapKey <- "map_api_key"

google_map(key = mapKey) %>%
  add_markers(data = x, info_window = "neighbourhood")
```

[image]

---

#### Further Reading

- [Simple features vignette](https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/articles/sf1.html#geometrycollection)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Google's free API is limited to 2,500 requests per day. Nominatim alternatively is provided by OSM, but without any API in R. But for this amount of data I wouldn't consider a web service. Do you have a licence for ArcGIS?

Maybe you can also aggregate your function by avoiding the assignments like this:

```
require(ggmap)
get_address <- function(df){
  revgeocode(c(as.numeric(df$longitude),as.numeric(df$latitude)))
}
```

Comment: I've never used arcGIS but I believe I can get access to the software through my university.

Comment: Did I understand your EDIT correctly that you just want to clip the points lying in this specific borough?

Comment: For my data, most of the observations have latitude and longitude coordinates but in many cases are missing the name of the borough.  It would be nice to be able to get both neighborhood name and borough name from these coordinates, but I would be happy just getting the borough.

Comment: Um. Where did you get your info that Nominatim has no "API in R"? https://github.com/hrbrmstr/nominatim Pls don't speak authoritatively when you don't know what you're talking about.

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion. What I really wanted to say is that nominatim has no library you can download with the package manager like ggmap.